# Haskell IO and arrays with recursion

Tags: arrays, haskell, recursion, io, functional-programming

I am having trouble writing a function with type
`Int -> IO [Int]` or `Int -> [IO Int]`

I have the following code that is not working:

```
createEIList :: Int -> IO [Int]
createEIList len = do
    cur <- createEI
    (return cur):(createEIList (len-1))
```

Where createEI is `createEI :: IO Int`

What is the best way to do something like this?

Comment: replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m [a], Study this type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep it close to what you originally had

```
createEIList :: Int -> IO [Int]
createEIList len = do
    cur <- createEI
    rest <- createEIList (len-1)
    return (cur:rest)
```

This way, you don't try to append `IO Int` to your list, but rather return the whole list lifting your `[Int]` to an `IO [Int]`

You also probably want a base case

```
createEIList 0 = return []
createEIList n = ...
```

So that the recursion actually terminates.

Also worth noting that you can remove the explicit recursion with the combinator

```
 replicateM :: Int -> IO a -> IO [a] -- Restricted for clarity
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to use this.

Comment: But wouldn't the `:` have a left argument of type `Int` and a right argument of `IO Int`?

Comment: @user2529202 Fixed, you pull explicitly bind it to a name to remove it's monadic wrapper

Comment: The `<-` removes the IO and then you can just cons it with the new element

Answer (score 2):

The last line should be `createEIList (len-1) >>= \a -> return (cur:a)`

Comment: I think it would be better to stick to the `do`-notation instead of lambda, since we're already in that.

Comment: I wanted to make sure that I could answer in one line rather than having to rewrite the whole thing or risk causing confusion.

Comment: This doesn't terminate.

Comment: @dave I think it will if you add a case for length being 0 ie. `createEIList 0 = return []`?

Comment: Without lambda - `createEIList (len-1) >>= return . (cur :)`

Answer (score 2):

```
createEIList :: Int -> IO Int    
createEIList len = createEI >>= return . replicate len
```

or

```
createEIList :: Int -> IO Int  
createEIList len = createEI >>= replicateM len . return
```

better solution:

```
createEIList :: Int -> IO Int
createEIList len = replicateM len createEI
```

tersest:

```
createEIList :: Int -> IO Int
createEIList = flip replicateM createEI
```

applicative:

```
import Control.Applicative
createEIList  len = replicate <$> pure len <*> createEI
createEIList' len = liftA2 replicate (pure len) createEI
```